# Why can we use task like this?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

```
task.ContinueWith( x => Process(x));

task.ContinueWith( Process)
```

I am wondering why both can work?

I thought ContinueWith needs at least one parameter of Task

Answer (score 5):

The lambda expression is being converted to a method group.

> **13.6 Method group conversions**
>
> Similar to the implicit anonymous method conversions described in §13.5, an implicit conversion exists
> from a method group (§14.1) to a compatible delegate type. If D is a
> delegate type, and E is an expression that is classified as a method
> group, then D is compatible with E if and only if E contains at least
> one method that is applicable in its normal form (§14.4.2.1) to any
> argument list (§14.4.1) having types and modifiers matching the
> parameter types and modifiers of D.
>
> The compile-time application of
> the conversion from E to D is the same as the compile-time processing
> of the delegate creation expression new D(E) (§14.5.10.3). Note that
> the existence of an implicit conversion from E to D just indicates
> that the set of applicable methods is not empty, but does not
> guarantee that the compile-time application of the conversion will
> succeed without error.

See http://en.csharp-online.net/ECMA-334:_13.6_Method_group_conversions for examples.

Answer (score 0):

Those two lines are essentially the same thing. the lower one is a method call, and the lambda expression above it is just being converted into a similar method call. Same thing, just expressed differently.

Comment: Well, it's not quite the same thing.  It's creating a new method with the same signature (but a different name) as some other method, and then calling that other method.  The only difference in the end result is an extra level in the stack trace (assuming it isn't optimized out, which it most likely will be).

Comment: @Servy: I know there are other things that happen behind the scenes - ie. overhead with the lambda expression, but it results in the same thing. :)

Answer (score 0):

Because `ContinueWith` expects an `Action<Task>` as parameter and `Process` has the right signature as well as `(x) => Process(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

x => Process(x) is creating a delegate.

A delegate is a type that references a method.

A Task represents an asynchronous operation.

An Action is a type of delegate.